# Can Roxy be used to deploy generic MarkLogic applications?

Tags: marklogic, roxy

I have developed a MarkLogic [application](https://gitlab.dyomedea.com/marklogic/orbeon-form-runner-persistence-layer/tree/master) which is neither an MVC nor a REST application (more precisely, it is a REST API which doesn't use the standard ML REST API).

I'd like to use [Roxy](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy) to package and deploy this application but Roxy includes either ML's REST API or MVC framework when you create a new project.

Is it possible to strip down what is deployed by Roxy or do I have to find other solutions such as [MarkLogic packaging](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/packaging-tutorial) which is much less features complete than Roxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the Deployer for a non-MarkLogic REST API application, I would start with an mvc application (`ml new my-app --app-type=mvc`), remove the provided source code (`rm -rf src`), then reset the URL rewriter and error handler

- url-rewriter=
- error-handler=

Then you can copy your code into src.

-- Update --

As grtjn has noted, this ticket was implemented in Roxy. Correct answer is now to use `--app-type=bare`.

Comment: It's working fine (I still have an error to fix probably due to a difference in the resulting HTTP server or database but this is probably not related to this question), thanks! What about adding a new "raw" or "generic" type of application to Roxy which would be less misleading and avoid to have to delete things?

Comment: I invite you to make that suggestion over on [GitHub](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/issues). There have been other cases where that would be useful.

Comment: This is done ([issue #362](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/issues/362)). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new Roxy project using the REST-type, you will notice that the src folder is empty, and the rest-api folder won't contain much either. If you are willing to ignore the rest-api folder, and rework a few settings in build.properties to match your own rewriter and such, then there is not much holding you back to deploy most kinds of MarkLogic applications.

You can also use `deploy src` instead of `deploy modules` to make it skip the deployment or the REST options and extensions.

HTH!

Comment: I have tried both your approach (rest type) and Dave Cassel's approach (mvc type) and both work but with rest type `ml <env> deploy modules` raises warning complaining that REST stuff are missing. I am thus led to prefer starting from a mvc type... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hence the suggestion to use `deploy src` instead. The error wouldn't be harmful by the way, but it doesn't look nice. We'll certainly look into adding a generic app-type to Roxy..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments on Dave's answer, a new Roxy app type has been introduced. You can now use:

```
ml new my-app --app-type=bare
```

That give amongst others an empty src folder, no rest-api, and no rewriter..

HTH!